# visibility cycling - org mode - save and restore folding state of sub trees

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to have a `SAVED` visibility in Org mode ?

Something like:

```
   ,-> FOLDED -> SAVED -> CHILDREN -> SUBTREE --.
   '--------------------------------------------'
```

akin to [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html).

`SAVED` would remember the exact folding state (recorded by the command `org-mode-save-folding-state-of-subtree`) of the subtree. The folding of the subtree would be restored to the saved state when switching from `FOLDED` to `SAVED`.

How can this be done in Org mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility. You can set a `VISIBILITY` property on each node to specify its initial visibility, and call `org-set-startup-visibility` (bound to `C-u C-u <TAB>`) to restore those saved settings.

You may be able to write a custom command to walk the tree and set the visibility property of each node based on its current state, but there's no built-in support for that.

Answer (score 0):

A file that, more or less, implements this functionality is available at the Emacs wiki [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/orgfold-separate-file.el).
The only difference is that it simply always saves/restores the folding state of all headlines (there is no separate `SAVED` visibility option). Just download the file and load it from your init file.