# emacs: saving org headline visibility

Tags: org-mode, osx, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, emacs25

I have an org file at `~/foo.org` it looks like this (see bottom of this question)

I reboot my pc every day, and the first thing I do is open this file.
Then I do the mundane task of pressing tab to expand the ** About me
headline.

Is it possible to save this visibility setting? or is it possible to tell emacs to "unfold" this particular heading upon file opening

What I tried: I googled around, there's a [guy](http://endlessparentheses.com/fine-tuning-subtree-visibility-in-org-mode.html)  who hints at this being possible, but he's very terse and it lacks a concrete example.

```
* Workshop

** Greetings, Introduction, Organization

- breaks
- drinking
  - vending machines for pops and coffee

** About me

- Flipchart
- 2009-2012: PIM researcher ([[http://tagstore.org]])
  - organizing files and folders
  - an alternative to strict hierarchies of folders
  - tagging
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33180?

Comment: how do you set the visibility property on a node ?

Comment: See http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html#Property-syntax for details about org properties. You can use `C-c C-x p` to set a property, e.g. to set `VISIBILITY` to `all` for the current node.

Answer (score 1):

Allright, go to the node you want to be visible on startup, press
C-c C-x p
then provide VISIBILITY and children

and on the next invocation it will look like something like this:
(in this case I tell emacs to keep the children of ** Greetings visible)

[image]

I still think it's ugly to have my "mind map" cluttered with metadata lines like `:PROPERTIES:`

but it seems folks are hesitant to tackle that
[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode
[ http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/28297

Comment: Yes it does look cluttered - so far the only way to deal with it I guess is to set the `org-special-keyword` face to be just visible above the background color.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this to try to minimize the appearance of the `:PROPERTIES:` line - my `default` face background is a dark gray "#171717" -

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-special-keyword nil :foreground "#333")
(set-face-attribute 'org-ellipsis nil :foreground "#555")
(setq org-ellipsis 'org-ellipsis)
(org-mode)
```